# generate stratified bootstrap resamples in R

Tags: r, dataframe, resampling

Assume I have a data frame with 3 variables and 7 rows

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0), V2=rnorm(7), V3=rnorm(7))
```

How can I create a bootstrapped data frame with say 20 rows, where the distribution of the zeros and ones in V1 is about the same, i.e. it should contain the same number of 0 and 1? thanks.

I looked at some packages, e.g. `boot`, but I don't want to compute a bootstrapped statistic, I just want the data set.

Comment: Are you looking for `df[sample(1:nrow(df),20,T),]`?

Comment: @nicola does this stratify the V1 columns to have equal amounts of 1s and 0s?

Comment: @spore234 What happened when you googled "r stratified sampling"? Can you please clarify why these links aren't helpful in your case.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your post properly. I thought you want to keep the same 0/1 proportions of the original dataset. Just try: `df[sample(1:nrow(df),20,T,prob=ave(df$V1,df$V1,FUN=function(x) 1/length(x))),]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sample_n` from `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  sample_n(10, replace=T)
```